# How to open text file with the help of button under any form?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ax

I have one text file(Notepad) put under resources node in AX 2012 AOT. Now, my task is to open this file with the help of button under any form.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc967403.aspx

Above link is helpful when creating temporary file for writing or reading.
Also, there is a form in AX 2012 named "smmDocuments" in which we can put text files of our use and we can open that file easily from there. I have researched and found that there is a class named "DocuAction" in AX 2012 to perform operations with text files.
But I am unable to understand how that thing is working.

///////////////////
I got it working as:

```
void clicked()
{
    //super();
   str sTempPath,
        sFileName = "notes.txt";
    SysResource::saveToTempFile(SysResource::getResourceNode(resourceStr(flow_for_address_book_txt)), false, "notes.txt");
    sTempPath = WinAPI::getTempPath();
    WinAPI::shellExecute(sTempPath+sFileName);
}
```

Thanks Jan B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not describe what actions you want to perform on your file.

Suppose you want to show the file to your user using the default program, then do:

```
void clicked()
{
    SysResource::saveToTempFile(SysResource::getResourceNode(resourceStr(MyImage), false, "notes.txt");
    WinAPI::shellExecute("notes.txt");
}
```

Use a temporary file instead of a hardcoded name.

You may also display the text in a form control:

```
void clicked()
{
    container con = SysResource::getResourceNodeData(SysResource::getResourceNode(resourceStr(MyImage), false, "notes.txt");
    infoStringControl.text(conpeek(con,1)); //Not sure how to use the container!
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying so Quikly. Currently i don't wanna perform any operation using code. i just wanna open a file. so, user can view it. I have done the code as u described above. Name of resource is "flow_for_address_book_txt" and filename is"flow for address book.txt". when i am clicking the button it is saying that "windows cannot find file flow_for_address_book_txt.txt Make sure you typed the name correctly and try again" @jan

Comment: Answer updated. If always a text file, I would go for the form control option.

Comment: @ Jan.. great stuff.. however, i am still not getting the text file which is being created temporarily using above code. temporary file is getting created under"C:\Users\mohdsaddaf.uzzamankh\AppData\Local\Temp". while WiNAPi is trying to find file under "C:\Windows\System32". Can you tell me, how to change the path to get that temporary file...